# Как найти элемент в списке если он находиться в другом списке?

Tags: python, list

Здрасьте, пишу помощницу.

Пример: Есть элемент списка «text_split». Он же есть и в списке «lst_cmd_write», который находиться в списке «lst_cmd».

Проблема: Почему python не видит элемент в глобальном списке «lst_cmd», но если уточнить(заменить на «lst_cmd_write») что он находиться в «lst_cmd_write», то видет?

Обязательно надо сохранить названия подсписков, так как списки - это база данных и в будущем она будет больше...

Код:

```
lst_cmd_start = ["открыть","открой","запустить","запусти",]
lst_cmd_write = ["записать", "запиши", "напиши", "написать","запишешь","запишете","запишите",]
lst_parasites = ["пожалуйста", "можешь", "будь добра",]
lst_greetings = ["привет","приветствую","приветик",]

lst_cmd = [lst_cmd_start, lst_cmd_write]
print(lst_cmd)
lst_global = [lst_cmd, lst_parasites, lst_greetings]


process = input("").lower()
text_split = process.split(" ")
print(text_split)

i_txt=0
i_lst=0
while len(text_split):
    if i_txt >= len(text_split):
        print("Вылет")
        break


#Проблема в lst_cmd - не работает, а lst_cmd_write - работает.
    elif text_split[i_txt] in lst_cmd:
        print("win")
        if text_split[i_txt] in lst_cmd_start:
            text_split.remove(text_split[i_txt])
            print("lst_cmd_start")

            i_txt = 0
            while len(text_split):
                if i_txt >= len(text_split):
                    my_file = open(r"C:\Users\berez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\BabyFile.txt", "w+")
                    my_file.write(" ".join(text_split))
                    my_file.close()
                    print("Записала!")
                    break

                elif text_split[i_txt] in lst_parasites:
                    text_split.remove(text_split[i_txt])
                    print("Паразит удалён")
                    i_txt = 0

                else:
                    i_txt += 1

        elif text_split[i_txt] in lst_cmd_write:
            text_split.remove(text_split[i_txt])
            print("lst_cmd_write")
            i_txt=0
            while len(text_split):
                if i_txt >= len(text_split):
                    my_file = open(r"C:\Users\berez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\BabyFile.txt", "w+")
                    my_file.write(" ".join(text_split))
                    my_file.close()
                    print("Записала!")
                    break

                elif text_split[i_txt] in lst_parasites:
                    text_split.remove(text_split[i_txt])
                    print("Паразит удалён")
                    i_txt=0

                else:
                    i_txt+=1

        else:
            print("Error")
    else:
        print("Error")
        i_txt+=1


#Можешь записать пожалуйста сделать стол
```

Comment: огромный кусок кода + не очень ясные комментарии. Советую уменьшить до минимально воспроизводимого кода согласно правилам сайта, обновить текст. Например, как понимать "python не видит"? Где объявление списка глобальным или почему он глобальный? Желательно русский подправить.  + не пишу базы данных, но что-то мне подсказывает, что делать их на списках - не лучшая идея:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*#Проблема в lst_cmd - не работает, а lst_cmd_write - работает.*  --  проблема не в том, что "не работает". Проблема в том, что вы не понимаете, что делаете вот в этом месте:

```
lst_cmd = [lst_cmd_start, lst_cmd_write]
```

Откройте менеджер переменных, и посмотрите, что такое `lst_cmd`. Вы с удивлением обнаружите, что это список из ДВУХ элементов. Один

```
lst_cmd[0]
Out[47]: ['открыть', 'открой', 'запустить', 'запусти']
```

и второй

```
lst_cmd[1]
Out[48]: ['записать','запиши','напиши','написать','запишешь','запишете','запишите']
```

А text_split[i_txt] - это ОДНА строка. Ну например `'записать'`

Поэтому неудивительно, что

```
text_split[i_txt] in lst_cmd
```

будет иметь значение `False`, в то время как

```
text_split[i_txt] in lst_cmd_write
```

будет иметь значение `True`

Я думаю, правильнее было бы написать

```
lst_cmd=lst_cmd_start+lst_cmd_write
```

Попробуйте. Думаю, хотя-бы указанную вами ошибку это должно исправить(про другие ошибки пока не говорю).

Comment: Сработало!!! Спасибо большое! Я ещё новичок в python и думал, что так:

`lst_cmd = [lst_cmd_start, lst_cmd_write]` 

получиться список в списке(к примеру так: `lst_cmd = [[молоко],[мясо]]`), но видимо переменные он не воспринимает...

P.S: А что за ещё ошибки?

Comment: Вам, как новичку - подскажу:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers